# Logcat (Debugging ) Over Wifi in android

Tags: android

Is there a way  where i can see my logcat result if i connect my  android device using Wifi (not a Usb data cable) basically to  Debug my application.If yes how do i go about it.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069212/adb-wifi-and-eclipse-how-i-can-configure

Answer (score 6):

no app required!

(1)
connect phone with usb, then type in command line:

adb tcpip 5555

you can disconnect your phone from usb now

(if the reason for using wifi is that usb does not work on your machine, just do the above on another computer

(2) find out the IP address of your mobile device (somewhere under settings .... phone status)

(3)
in command line type:

adb connect [IP of your mobile]

NOTE: all devices need to be connected to same wifi; avoid using public wifis

Comment: The biggest problem with this common method is that if you device doesn't support USB cable connection to any computer, then it isn't going to work. I have an Android car stereo that simply will not allow connection to a PC.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use a program called "wifi ADB" from the playstore.  and run adb connect ipaddress from the server.. your logcat traffic will then appear in eclipse logcat